# keep getting 400 while trying to run a function through ajax

Tags: ajax

i was trying to run an insert query in wordpress and error 400 bad request on post keep coming

```
$.ajax({
            url:wp_url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data['success']){
                    $('#newsletter')[0].reset();
                    $('.msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data['success']+'</div>');
                    //alert('hello');

                }
                if(data['failed']){
                    $('#newsletter')[0].reset();
                    $('.msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+data['failed']+'</div>');
                    //alert(data['failed']);
                }
                setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert').slideUp('slow'); }, 9000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: That's `wp_url` retrieving an error... check that url code or give us all the scripts to see what's wrong.

Comment: no problem with wp_url, its returning the correct url. i think the problem is with the type : 'POST'

Comment: maybe the `formData`? are you stringify it?

Comment: no, i don't want to stringify it

Comment: POST http://localhost/project/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)    this is the error

Comment: Check, this should help: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-development-admin-ajax-php-error-400/

Comment: <?php
  function user_add(){
  $name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
 global $wpdb;
  $table_name = 'healthy_newsletter';
  $result = $wpdb->insert($table_name,array('name'=>$name,'email'=>$email));
  if ($result) {
    $html['success'] = "Your Enquiry have been successfully submitted";
  }
   else{
         $html['failed'] = "Something Went Wrong Please Try Again!!";
   }
  echo json_encode($html);
  die();
  }
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_user_add', 'user_add' );
  add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_user_add', 'user_add' );
  ?>
this is the function